# Match a string against a list of stored variables

Tags: jquery, variables, pattern-matching

Using JS/jQuery, what is the best way to do this?

I have 5 variables:

```
var fruit1 = "apple";
var fruit2 = "mango";
var fruit3 = "orange";
var fruit4 = "banana";
var fruit5 = "melon";
```

Then I have a list element with a certain fruit which is clicked:

```
<li id="banana">Banana</li>
```

I get its ID in the script:

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
    var selectedfruit = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

How do I match `selectedfruit` with the variable list so that it returns `fruit4` with which I can do stuff with?

Secondary question, should I put my variable list in an array?

Thanks very much.

**Edit: I am very sorry, but I have made a huge mistake**

I need to validate the `selectedfruit` with the variable **name**, not the variable **contents**.

So, the markup would be like this:

`<li id="fruit4">Mystery fruit</li>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely a job for an array.

```
var fruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange", "banana", "melon"];
```

Then in your click handler, you can search this array, and get its index.

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
    // Note: This will return -1, if it's not in the array
    var selectedfruit = $.inArray($(this).attr("id"), fruits); // 3 (arrays are zero-indexed)
});
```

**UPDATE** Based off of your update, I would use an object instead.

```
var fruits = {
    fruit1: "apple",
    fruit2: "mango",
    fruit3: "orange",
    fruit4: "banana",
    fruit5: "melon"
};
```

Then you can use the ID to get the value and compare.

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
    var selectedfruit = fruits[$(this).attr("id")];  // banana
});
```

Comment: Thank you for not missing my edit. Your object idea was perfect for what I am trying to do. My code works exactly how my update describes and now thanks to you, it is functional.

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like below:

```
var fruits = {
  fruit1 : "apple",
  fruit2 : "mango",
  fruit3 : "orange",
  fruit4 : "banana",
  fruit5 : "melon"
};

$("li").on("click", function() {
    var selectedfruit = $(this).attr("id");
    alert( fruits[selectedfruit] );
});
```

#### But with array

```
var fruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange", "banana", "melon"],
    selectedfruit  = $(this).attr("id");

$("li").on("click", function() {
    var index = $.inArray( fruits, selectedfruit  );
    if( index >= 0 ) // checking that fruit exists in the array, if not index === -1
       var fruitIndex = 'fruit' + (index + 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any benefit of using an array vs. an object?

Answer (score 3):

Could you use a javascript array instead of individual variables?

```
var fruits=new Array("apple","mango","orange", "banana", "melon");
$.inArray("mango", fruits)
```

See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5phe4/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I decided that an object was better for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try making your variables an array:

```
var fruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange", "banana", "melon"];
```

Then grab the index of the array using `indexOf()`:

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
    var fruitIndex = fruits.indexOf($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Since some browsers don't support `indexOf()`, you can use the following to force their support:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) { 
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

You can then interact with the clicked fruit element like this:

```
alert(fruits[fruitIndex]);
```

Comment: @Rocket - Good point. I edited the post to address this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my question due to an error on my part. Rocket and I have decided that an object would be best, but I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much better if you stored your variables in an array. Then you can find the match easily by using `jQuery.inArray`.

Answer (score 2):

yes you should put your variable in an array. It has been a while coding in jquery but I think I can give it a try :

```
     var fruits[] = new Array(your variable values)
     $(document).ready(function() {
          //click handler event and then take the value of id attribute as you mentioned
          //iterate over the loop and then store index and do something with that if you 
          //want. 
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought that he needs some syntax help;Now updated. Better answer already exists:

```
var fruits = ["apple", "mango", "orange", "banana", "melon"];
$("li").click(function() {
    var selectedfruit = $(this).attr("id");
    for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        if (selectedfruit == "fruit" + (i+1)) {
            alert(fruits[i] + " is pressed");
        }
        }
    });​
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because the user could click `fruit3` or any of the other fruits.